# How do I use Twitter's REST API using VB in an ASP.NET web application to implement a search for tweets?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter

I am only familiar with using the Twitter Search API in JavaScript which does not require authentication, and I can't seem to grasp the concept of authenticating and making calls server-side in VB. I have tried various tutorials such as those using open source libraries (Twitterizer, TweetSharp, etc) and I am completely lost which leads me to believe I am missing some fundamental concepts. Any advice on where to start would be greatly appreciated, as I have just been blindly researching this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a lot of luck using the [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) library and following the Twitter [developer guide](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) for OAuth authentication.

Probably the "trickiest" thing I found is to make sure I used the OAuth1Authenticator object to star off my authentication and subsequent API requests. My code typically starts out like this:

```
Dim Client AS New RestClient(baseUrl)

Client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken
                          (MvcApplication.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
                           MvcApplication.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
                           _authInfo.accessToken,
                           _authInfo.accessTokenSecret)

Dim Request As New RestRequest("search/tweets.json", Method.GET);
                               request.AddParameter("include_entities", "true")
```

You can piece together the rest from there. Note, this is using the v1 API, you should look more into the v1.1 API

Comment: Thank you, I will see what I can figure out using RestSharp. I hadn't tried that one out yet.

Comment: I ended up using Twitterizer in the end, but after playing around with RestSharp, your code example greatly helped me understand what it was I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. Just keep in mind that Twitterizer appears to be losing its primary development support, so you'll wan to be mindful of the 1.1 API Twitter is pushing out to make sure everything still works.